# Output of JSP Script is displayed before the HTML

Tags: jsp

This is my Code in Jsp which should print a table by getting all the items from my database. But what actually happens is that all the output of the jsp snippet is displayed first.

```
<%@page import="java.io.PrintWriter"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="pos.dbconnection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>View All the Items</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action='viewitems.jsp'>
        <table border='1'>
    <% 
         Connection con = dbconnection.getconnection();
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from panch.raw;");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.print("<tr>"+
        "<th>Raw_Id</th>"+
        "<th>Raw_Name</th>"+
        "<th>Raw_Quantity</th>"+
        "<th>Raw_CostPrice</th>"+
        "</tr>");


        while(rs.next())
        { 
        pw.print("<tr>");
        pw.print("<td>"+rs.getString("raw_id")+"</td>");
        pw.print("<td>"+rs.getString("raw_name")+"</td>");
        pw.print("<td>"+rs.getString("raw_quantity")+"</td>");
        pw.print("<td>"+rs.getString("raw_cost")+"</td>");
         pw.print("<td><input name='id' value='"+rs.getString("raw_id")+
                 "' hidden='true'/> <input type='submit' value='Edit'/>"+
                 "</td>");
        pw.print("</tr>");
        } %>
    </table> 

  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the OUtput

```
<tr>
 <th>Raw_Id</th><th>Raw_Name</th>
 <th>Raw_Quantity</th> 
 <th>Raw_CostPrice</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Ghee</td>
  <td>5000</td>
  <td>80</td>
  <td><input name='id' value='1' hidden='true'/> 
      <input type='submit' value='Edit'/></td>
 </tr>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>View All the Items</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action='viewitems.jsp'>
        <table border='1'>

    </table> 

  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am running this in Glassfish Server In Netbeans.
Please tell me how to rectify it?

Comment: 1) use the `out` implicit object (see Issam's answer); 2) **do not use scriptlets**, use either [MVC pattern](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/11/mvc-architecture-with-servlets-and-jsp/), or at least the [SQL tag library](http://www.devmanuals.com/tutorials/java/jsp/jstl/sql/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use out.println, like below

```
<%@page import="java.io.PrintWriter"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="pos.dbconnection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>View All the Items</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action='viewitems.jsp'>
        <table border='1'>
    <% 
         Connection con = dbconnection.getconnection();
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from panch.raw;");

        out.println("<tr>"+
        "<th>Raw_Id</th>"+
        "<th>Raw_Name</th>"+
        "<th>Raw_Quantity</th>"+
        "<th>Raw_CostPrice</th>"+
        "</tr>");


        while(rs.next())
        { 
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>"+rs.getString("raw_id")+"</td>");
        out.println("<td>"+rs.getString("raw_name")+"</td>");
        out.println("<td>"+rs.getString("raw_quantity")+"</td>");
        out.println("<td>"+rs.getString("raw_cost")+"</td>");
         out.println("<td><input name='id' value='"+rs.getString("raw_id")+
                 "' hidden='true'/> <input type='submit' value='Edit'/>"+
                 "</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        } %>
    </table> 

  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. As adviced on comment avoid the use of scriptlet and use MVC pattern